# pyserial doesn't accept port from script

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I have a nice little script, which should give me the open serial port in `def serial_port():` Which is `'/dev/ttyACM0'` as usual. However my next `function def connect_phone():` doesn't accept this as an input (giving me an `serial.serialutil.SerialException:`, but only when its typed manually. Does anyone get whats the issue here?

the complete script is this:

```
import sys
import glob
import serial
import time

def serial_ports():
    """ Lists serial port names

        :raises EnvironmentError:
            On unsupported or unknown platforms
        :returns:
            A list of the serial ports available on the system
    """
    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        ports = ['COM%s' % (i + 1) for i in range(256)]
    elif sys.platform.startswith('linux') or sys.platform.startswith('cygwin'):
        # this excludes your current terminal "/dev/tty"
        ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty[A-Za-z]*')
    elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
        ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty.*')
    else:
        raise EnvironmentError('Unsupported platform')

    result = []
    for port in ports:
        try:
            s = serial.Serial(port)
            s.close()
            result.append(port)
        except (OSError, serial.SerialException):
            pass
    return result

def connect_phone():
        ser = serial.Serial("'"+serial_ports()[0]+"'", #'/dev/ttyACM0',     (this is the problem here)          
                        460800,
                        timeout=5,
                        xonxoff = False,
                        rtscts = False,
                        bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
                        parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
                        stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

        ser.write(bytes('AT+CGMI' + '\r\n'))
        ser.timeout = 1
        ser.write('AT+CGMM' + '\r\n')
        ser.timeout = 1
        time.sleep(2)
        ser.write('AT+CNMI=?\r') #checks whether mobile phone can receive delivery reports
        response = ser.read(999)
        return response

print("'"+serial_ports()[0]+"'")
time.sleep(1)
print(connect_phone())
```

Comment: why do you add `"'"` ? You create wrong text with extra `'`. In direct text `'/dev/ttyACM0'` this `'` is not part of text but information for you and Python that it is text, not variable. Try `Serial(serial_ports()[0],460800,...)`

Comment: as easy as that?! I thought I tried this before!! suddenly it works out!